# S3 public read access restricted by IP range for object uploaded by third-party

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I am trying to accomplish the following scenario:

1) Account A uploads a file to an S3 bucket owned by account B. At upload I specify full control for Account owner B

```
s3_client.upload_file(
    local_file, 
    bucket, 
    remote_file_name, 
    ExtraArgs={'GrantFullControl': 'id=<AccountB_CanonicalID>'}
)
```

2) Account B defines a bucket policy that limits the access to the objects by IP (see below)

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowIPs",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketB/*",
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        <CIDR1>,
                        <CIDR2>
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I get access denied if I try to download the file as anonymous user, even from the specific IP range. If at upload I add public read permission for everyone then I can download the file from any IP.

```
s3_client.upload_file(
    local_file, bucket, 
    remote_file_name, 
    ExtraArgs={
        'GrantFullControl': 'id=AccountB_CanonicalID', GrantRead':'uri="http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/global/AllUsers"'
    }
)
```

Question: is it possible to upload the file from Account A to Account B but still restrict public access by an IP range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible. According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/access-control-overview.html):

> Bucket Policy – For your bucket, you can add a bucket policy to grant
>   other AWS accounts or IAM users permissions for the bucket and the
>   objects in it. Any object permissions apply only to the objects that
>   the bucket owner creates. Bucket policies supplement, and in many
>   cases, replace ACL-based access policies.

However, there is a workaround for this scenario. The problem is that the owner of the uploaded file is Account A. We need to upload the file in such a way that the owner of the file is Account B. To accomplish this we need to:

1. In Account B create a role for trusted entity (select "Another AWS account" and specify Account A). Add upload permission for the bucket.
2. In Account A create a policy that allows AssumeRole action and as resource specify the ARN of the role created in step 1.

To upload the file from boto3 you can use the following code. Note the use of cachetools to deal with limited TTL of temporary credentials.

```
import logging
import sys
import time

import boto3

from cachetools import cached, TTLCache

CREDENTIALS_TTL = 1800
credentials_cache = TTLCache(1, CREDENTIALS_TTL - 60)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger()


def main():
    local_file = sys.argv[1]
    bucket = '<bucket_from_account_B>'
    client = _get_s3_client_for_another_account()
    client.upload_file(local_file, bucket, local_file)
    logger.info('Uploaded to %s to %s' % (local_file, bucket))


@cached(credentials_cache)
def _get_s3_client_for_another_account():
    sts = boto3.client('sts')
    response = sts.assume_role(
        RoleArn='<arn_of_role_created_in_step_1>',
        DurationSeconds=CREDENTIALS_TTL
    )
    credentials = response['Credentials']
    credentials = {
        'aws_access_key_id': credentials['AccessKeyId'],
        'aws_secret_access_key': credentials['SecretAccessKey'],
        'aws_session_token': credentials['SessionToken'],
    }
    return boto3.client('s3', 'eu-central-1', **credentials)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```